# Moodle uploading file issue Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

Im facing an issue with moodle, when trying to upload some kind of files in add question page like docx,xlsx im getting following error at console:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at Function.O.getValue (http://example.com/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.13.0/yui-moodlesimple.js:14670:14)
at Y_Node.DEFAULT_GETTER (http://example.com/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.13.0/yui-moodlesimple.js:30339:24)
at Y_Node._get (http://example.com/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.13.0/yui-moodlesimple.js:30422:41)
at Y_Node.get (http://example.com/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.13.0/yui-moodlesimple.js:30395:24)
at IO._uploadComplete (http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?3.13.0/datatype-xml-parse/datatype-xml-parse.js&3.13.0/io-xdr/io-xdr.js&3.13.0/io-form/io-form.js&3.13.0/io-upload-iframe/io-upload-iframe.js&3.13.0/queue-promote/queue-promote.js&3.13.0/io-queue/io-queue.js&3.13.0/event-resize/event-resize.js&3.13.0/dd-ddm/dd-ddm.js&3.13.0/dd-ddm-drop/dd-ddm-drop.js&3.13.0/dd-proxy/dd-proxy.js&3.13.0/dd-constrain/dd-constrain.js&3.13.0/dd-drop/dd-drop.js&3.13.0/dd-scroll/dd-scroll.js&3.13.0/dd-drop-plugin/dd-drop-plugin.js&3.13.0/dd-delegate/dd-delegate.js:724:44)
at Y_Node.<anonymous> (http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?3.13.0/datatype-xml-parse/datatype-xml-parse.js&3.13.0/io-xdr/io-xdr.js&3.13.0/io-form/io-form.js&3.13.0/io-upload-iframe/io-upload-iframe.js&3.13.0/queue-promote/queue-promote.js&3.13.0/io-queue/io-queue.js&3.13.0/event-resize/event-resize.js&3.13.0/dd-ddm/dd-ddm.js&3.13.0/dd-ddm-drop/dd-ddm-drop.js&3.13.0/dd-proxy/dd-proxy.js&3.13.0/dd-constrain/dd-constrain.js&3.13.0/dd-drop/dd-drop.js&3.13.0/dd-scroll/dd-scroll.js&3.13.0/dd-drop-plugin/dd-drop-plugin.js&3.13.0/dd-delegate/dd-delegate.js:569:34)
at Y.Subscriber._notify (http://example.com/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.13.0/yui-moodlesimple.js:26572:35)
at Y.Subscriber.notify (http://example.com/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.13.0/yui-moodlesimple.js:26601:24)
at Y.CustomEvent._notify (http://example.com/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.13.0/yui-moodlesimple.js:26264:17)
at Y.CustomEvent._procSubs (http://example.com/theme/yui_combo.php?rollup/3.13.0/yui-moodlesimple.js:26390:36)
```

This issue occuring only with some computers
for example with computer1 its working perfectly with all browsers, but for computer2 its not workink at all browsers
a seconde note that some files are uploading with no errors like png, jpg files

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

In httpd.conf

Find the line

```
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
```

comment the line:

```
#LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
```

Restar Apache